# Trying to solve a 4D system that gives me an error: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

When I try solving for all other combination of states aside from q (like e,p,i) I am able to solve; however when I include q, I can a `{}`

Any suggestions on how I can approach it?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

de = f s/(h + s) es - \[Mu]n e q en - fp e p q ep - fip p i e q ei - 
   rh - rp p - ri i;
dq = f s/(h + s) qs - \[Mu]n e q qn - fp e p q qp - fip p i e q qi;
dp = fp e p q - fip i p - mp p;
di = fip p i e q - mi i;

Equs = FullSimplify[Solve[{de == 0 dp == 0, di == 0}, {e, p, i}]]
Equs = FullSimplify[
  Solve[{de == 0, dq == 0, dp == 0, di == 0}, {e, q, p, i}]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that a comma is missing in your input of Equs.

I fear there is no general solution for `{de == 0, dq == 0, dp == 0, di == 0}` that is valid for arbitrary values of the parameters. However, there are solutions for specific values of the parameters. Consider the following:

We first solve: `de == 0, dp == 0, di == 0`:

```
sol1 = FullSimplify[Solve[{de == 0, dp == 0, di == 0}, {e, p, i}]];
```

This works and gives 4 different solutions. We may check if these are o.k.:

```
{de == 0, dp == 0, di == 0} /. sol1 // Simplify
(* {{True, True, True}, {True, True, True}, {True, True, True}, {True, 
  True, True}} *)
```

Now we only need to solve: `de == 0` for the different solutions in sol1:

```
FullSimplify[Solve[{dq == 0} /. sol1[[1]], {q}]]
.
.
FullSimplify[Solve[{dq == 0} /. sol1[[4]], {q}]]
```

Every time the solution is an empty list. This means that there exists no general solution that is valid for arbitrary parameters. Therefore we may search for solutions that are valid only for specific values of the parameters. This can be done with Reduce. E.g. for sol1[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taPEe.png)]:

```
FullSimplify[Reduce[{dq == 0} /. sol1[[1]], {q}]]
```

This gives 4 lengthy solutions with different parameters:

[image]